# MS Access DLookUp from different table

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, StudentT and LessonT, and two Forms, StudentF and LessonF.
I also have a combo box in the LessonF to connect StudentID from the StudentT.

When a user selects a student from the combo box on LessonF, I'd like the LessonDuration field on the LessonT to grab the default value by looking up the DefaultLessonDuration from the StudentT. But I want to be able to also edit the value. Can this be done?

I think I need to use the DLookUp for the LessonDuration field somehow, but can't figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

Starting from:

[image]

I created a form from the Lessons table then gave it an unbound combobox to select students (no control source) and a few more controls.  only the combo box started as visible.  The main question was where to allow editing the lesson duration.  I felt a temporarily visisble textbox & a save button set a good balance between a messagebox and a whole pop up form.  Note if you add all 3 columns from Students then there will be no need for a dlookup later.

[image]

```
Private Sub cmbStudents_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtLessonDuration = Me.cmbStudents.Column(2)
'Me.txtLessonDuration = DLookup("DefaultLessonDuration", "Students", "StudentID = " & Me.cmbStudents)
Me.txtLessonDuration.Visible = True
Me.lblLessonDuration.Visible = True
Me.cmdSaveLesson.Visible = True


End Sub

Private Sub cmdSaveLesson_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Lessons")
rs.AddNew
rs!StudentID = Me.cmbStudents
rs!LessonDuration = Me.txtLessonDuration
rs.Update
Me.cmbStudents.SetFocus 'can't hide control with focus
Me.txtLessonDuration.Visible = False
Me.lblLessonDuration.Visible = fasle
Me.cmdSaveLesson.Visible = False
Me.Requery
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Whatever controls you use the technology behind the events is the same.

Comment: Wow..this is way over my level at the moment. Thanks for showing this.  
To be honest, I have no clue what the codes mean, and where they even go...  
I thought I could just have the default value for the LessonDuration be the following:  
=DLookUp("DefaultLessonDuration","CurrentStudentQ","StudentID=" & StudentCombo)  
and all it does is just give me 0 for every student. Could you explain to me why the above DLookUp doesn't work for default value?  Thanks again for the work you've already put in this.

Comment: in my example.  every time the combobox is used to select a different student it then uses dlookup to set a textbox to that students DefaultLessonDuration.  I suggest trying to reproduce my example in a blank database.   Based on your example your dlookup would work if you replaced CurrentStudentQ with StudentT but I doubt that is the problem  Try Debugging your Dlookup using the Immediate Window (scroll down to immediate window here: https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp)

Comment: After about half a day spent, I found this to work for me using AfterUpdate:  

LessonDuration = DLookUp("DefaultLessonDuration","StudentT","StudentID=" & StudentCombo)

I feel I was probably not asking the question properly. Thank you for your time mazoula!

Answer (score 0):

This is using AfterUpdate for the combobox:

LessonDuration = DLookUp("DefaultLessonDuration","StudentT","StudentID=" & StudentCombo)